# URL execution time on linux server

Tags: linux, php, cron

i am using `ubuntu server`and i am sending mails through cronjob. There is little problem that i want to know the execution time of the URL which is executed via cronjob.

For example

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q https://anydomain.com/sendmail.php
```

Please tell me that how can i find the execution time of `sendmail.php`

even i tried to read the logs of cronjob but i didn't find proper answer.

Comment: Have the PHP file log its execution time to a file. See http://php.net/microtime for info on how.

Comment: You can use 'time' to measure the execution time of your wget command. The output can be redirected to a file.

`time wget -q https://anydomain.com/sendmail.php >> /tmp/time.sendmail.log`

Comment: Mr. Deagh, i tried it but not working, log file remains blank.

Comment: What is the server running? Apache does not log it by default, but it can be configured to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **deagh** has mentioned in the comments you can use *time* to measure the execution of a command. You will need to wrap the command in parentheses in order to be treated as one command for the stdout.

```
(time wget -q https://anydomain.com/sendmail.php) &> /tmp/time.sendmail.log
```

This will log the output in the tmp file.